# Is there a way to configure user logins to be case-insensitive in WMX (JTX) for ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-workflow-manager

I have some users who login on different workstations and the case of the username is different: John.Doe might be john.doe on another workstation.  I would like WMX to treat this as the same user.  I figure this might addresses by a windows configuration change, but I'm hoping I can leave the OS alone and just have WMX ignore case.

Comment: Tell your IT guy you should really be using a domain with roaming user accounts.

Comment: I'm 99% certain that they are the same account: user logs in with the same domain\username on both workstations.

Comment: Huh, don't know then, that is odd indeed.